# libodb2.4 did not support container in container, is there any work around?

Tags: c++, serialization, orm, persistence, odb

I have a project that needs to use C++ and Qt. And it also need persist object in filesystem. I found libodb-2.4 is a perfect solution. But it can not support the value that container in container directly, But the data struct in project must be stored with container in container.

Current work around is to change container value type in container to be a object type which persist in db, then I can store container in container. But after that, I have to manager more objects relationship just for the container value in container, and the project becomes more compliex.

Is there any other solutions or libs can solve this problem? Or serialize the object to store is a better solution?

example:

```
class A {

};

class B {
std::vector<A> a;
// other member
};

class C {
std::map<int, B>
int id;
// other member.
};
```

I can't store C in sqlite by **odb** directly.

Comment: Q: Can you show us some example code?  Q: Does [this link](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/manual.xhtml#5) suggest any alternatives for you?

Comment: @paulsm4 I have add example code in question.

Comment: I have read the menu and found one alternative for work,. I add serialize method in class B and class A, when to store class C, first serialize class B to string, then containers in container becomes strings in container, this is a function of  **odb** called **virtual member** . But odb can't support vector in virtual member type, so the serialization in B have to produce a string.